# DefaultHttpClient execute() method sometimes does not return

Tags: android

In my applicaiton, I use a shared `DefaultHttpClient` to perform all http requests. In one of my UI there is a `ListView` used to show data requested from server and a 'query more' button used to request more data from server by starting an `AsycnTask` to peform the requst.

Items of the `ListView` are clickable. When clicking one item my app will start a new Activity used to show details data of the clicked item. The details data request is performed in another `AsyncTask`, and there is the problem: when i click 'query more' button and then almost in the same time (maybe a little later) i click one item of the ListView, the latter request(details data) is normally responsed but the former request(more data)seems to be stuck in `doInBackground` of the `AsyncTask` and never return, any ideas?

Here is the code of 'query more' task:

```
private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Group<Venue>> {

    private Exception mReason = null;
    private boolean mMore = false;
    private int mFrom;

    public SearchTask(boolean moreSearch,int startFrom){
        mMore = moreSearch;
        mFrom = startFrom;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "SearchTask: onPreExecute()");
        if(!mMore) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            setLoadingView();               
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public Group<Venue> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return search(mFrom,Anywhered.QUERY_LIMIT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mReason = e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Group<Venue> venues) {  
               ..... //omitted
           }

    public Group<Venue> search(int from,int limit) throws AnywhereException, LocationException,
            IOException {

        Anywhere anywhere = ((Anywhered) getApplication()).getAnywhere();

        Location location = ((Anywhered) getApplication()).getLastKnownLocationOrThrow();

        NearbyVenues nvs  = anywhere.venues(LocationUtils
                .createAnywhereLocation(location), mSearchHolder.query,from, limit);
        Group<Venue> venues = nvs.getNearybys();

        return venues;
    }
}

venues method will eventually call DefaultHttpClient execute() method to perform request data from server.
```